# Hide Activity without finish()

Tags: android

I want my application to launch another activity/application (in this case, the Browser application), but currently when the user presses the Back button to exit the Browser, they return back to my Activity.

How can I make it so they do not come back to my activity after leaving the Browser, **but** if they relaunch my application later, the `Activity` stack of my application is as it was previously (i.e., cannot `finish()`, because that will remove the current `Activity` from the stack)?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

in [`Activity.onActivityResult()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult%28int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent%29) of the `Activity` that launched the Browser, call [moveTaskToBack(true)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#moveTaskToBack%28boolean%29).  Note: this requires that the Browser was launched with [Activity#startActivityForResult()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29)

Answer (score 0):

You can't control that -- it's an inherent feature of the operating system, and you're talking about affecting behaviors of **other** applications.  The best you can do is control the behavior of **your own** application.  If you need fine-grained control over what you want the user to be able to do in the web browser, have you considered using a WebView instead?

Comment: i got the answer, in onactivityResult of the browser parent activity i write movetasktoback(true)

Comment: Yes, if all you wanted was to prevent your own activity from becoming visible again after you launched the browser (but you want Android to retain the current activity stack, in case you want to return to the activity later), then [moveTaskToBack()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#moveTaskToBack%28boolean%29) is the appropriate solution.  I'll update the question to reflect what you actually wanted (you said you want to disable the Back button, which is **not** what you were actually looking to do). Accept your own answer - I'll upvote to offset the reputation.